# Attaching timeseries to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
"2023-09-07 13:22" type1 12.7
"2023-09-07 14:07" type2 101.1
```

And separately a dataframe with reg spaced timeseries for each type:

```
                   type1     type2
2023-09-07 08:00       1         2
2023-09-07 08:15       3         4
2023-09-07 08:30       5         6
...
2023-09-07 13:15       7         8
2023-09-07 13:30       9        10      
2023-09-07 13:45      11        12
2023-09-07 14:00      13        14
2023-09-07 14:15      15        16
2023-09-07 14:30      17        18
...
```

I'd like to attach (as a row) to each line in the first dataframe 2 (or N) values from the second dataframe starting from the first timestamp after given.

So in this case, the answer would be

```
"2023-09-07 13:22" type1 12.7    9 11
"2023-09-07 14:07" type2 101.1  16 18
```

I could loop over the rows in the first dataframe, and each time find a slice in the second dataframe, but that's pretty slow. Was wondering if there's a better solution. Seems like a pretty common task.

Thank you.

Code to generate input dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["date", "type", "val"])
df1.loc[0] = [pd.to_datetime("2023-09-07 13:22:00"), "type1", 12.1]
df1.loc[1] = [pd.to_datetime("2023-09-07 14:07:00"), "type2", 101.1]
df1 = df1.set_index("date")
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(["2023-09-07 08:00", "2023-09-07 08:15","2023-09-07 08:30", "2023-09-07 13:15","2023-09-07 13:30", "2023-09-07 13:45","2023-09-07 14:00", "2023-09-07 14:15","2023-09-07 14:30"])
df2["type1"] = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
df2["type2"] = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
```

Comment: Yes, this is a `merge_asof`

Comment: @mozway Thanks, I can see it as a merge_asof if I wanted to attach the first value in the second column. How do you do it with a slice of values from the merge_asof timestamp?

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible input (as code)?

Comment: @mozway Sure, please see the code at the bottom of the question

Comment: thanks, see below for a vectorial approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pd.merge_asof` + slicing as next step:

Input dataframes (sorted by index):

```
df1

                      type  value
time                             
2023-09-07 13:22:00  type1   12.7
2023-09-07 14:07:00  type2  101.1

df2

                     type1  type2
time                             
2023-09-07 08:00:00      1      2
2023-09-07 08:15:00      3      4
2023-09-07 08:30:00      5      6
2023-09-07 13:15:00      7      8
2023-09-07 13:30:00      9     10
2023-09-07 13:45:00     11     12
2023-09-07 14:00:00     13     14
2023-09-07 14:15:00     15     16
2023-09-07 14:30:00     17     18
```

---

```py
N = 2

df2["time_tmp"] = df2.index
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction="forward")
df1[list(range(N))] = tmp.apply(
    lambda x: df2.loc[x["time_tmp"] :, x["type"]][:N].values,
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
                      type  value   0   1
time                                     
2023-09-07 13:22:00  type1   12.7   9  11
2023-09-07 14:07:00  type2  101.1  16  18
```

---

EDIT: "Safer" version, using `np.pad` (if there fewer values in row than N):

```py
def fn(row):
    vals = df2.loc[row["time_tmp"] :, row["type"]][:N].values
    if len(vals) < N:
        vals = np.pad(
            vals, mode="constant", pad_width=(0, N - len(vals)), constant_values=-1
        )
    return vals


df2["time_tmp"] = df2.index
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction="forward")
df1[list(range(N))] = tmp.apply(
    fn,
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
print(df1)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks - I haven't realized I can pass a list of columns for an assignment!

Comment: @LazyCat I've addded "safer" version (in case there is fewer result values in row than N - in this case it returns -1)

Answer (score 3):

For a fully vectorial approach, craft a rolled DataFrame with numpy's [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), then [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 2

# ensure date is the index
df2 = (df2.set_index('date')
          .rename_axis(columns='type')
       )

# create the sliding window
# reshape to "melted" format
tmp = (pd.DataFrame(swv(df2, N, axis=0)
                    .reshape(-1, N),
                    index=df2.iloc[:-N+1].stack(dropna=False).index)
         .reset_index('type')
       )

# merge_asof
out = pd.merge_asof(df1, tmp,
                    left_index=True, right_index=True,
                    by='type', direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
                      type    val   0   1
date                                     
2023-09-07 13:22:00  type1   12.1   9  11
2023-09-07 14:07:00  type2  101.1  16  18
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
                      type   0   1
date                              
2023-09-07 08:00:00  type1   1   3
2023-09-07 08:00:00  type2   2   4
2023-09-07 08:15:00  type1   3   5
2023-09-07 08:15:00  type2   4   6
2023-09-07 08:30:00  type1   5   7
2023-09-07 08:30:00  type2   6   8
2023-09-07 13:15:00  type1   7   9
2023-09-07 13:15:00  type2   8  10
2023-09-07 13:30:00  type1   9  11
2023-09-07 13:30:00  type2  10  12
2023-09-07 13:45:00  type1  11  13
2023-09-07 13:45:00  type2  12  14
2023-09-07 14:00:00  type1  13  15
2023-09-07 14:00:00  type2  14  16
2023-09-07 14:15:00  type1  15  17
2023-09-07 14:15:00  type2  16  18
```

*NB. If desired (for instance to get incomplete slices) you can [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) the DataFrame before `swv`.*

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 3

# ensure date is the index
df2 = (df2.set_index('date')
          .rename_axis(columns='type')
       )

# create the sliding window
# reshape to "melted" format
tmp = (pd.DataFrame(swv(np.pad(df2.astype(float), ((0, N-1), (0, 0)),
                               constant_values=np.nan),
                        N, axis=0)
                    .reshape(-1, N),
                    index=df2.stack(dropna=False).index)
         .reset_index('type')
       )

# merge_asof
out = pd.merge_asof(df1, tmp,
                    left_index=True, right_index=True,
                    by='type', direction='forward')
```

Output:

```
                      type    val     0     1     2
date                                               
2023-09-07 13:22:00  type1   12.1   9.0  11.0  13.0
2023-09-07 14:07:00  type2  101.1  16.0  18.0   NaN
```

Without padding, since the second row has an incomplete match the output would have been:

```
                      type    val    0     1     2
date                                              
2023-09-07 13:22:00  type1   12.1  9.0  11.0  13.0
2023-09-07 14:07:00  type2  101.1  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Should be `reshape(-1, N)`, right?

Comment: Also from testing, better to add `stack(dropna = False)` otherwise shapes get mismatched if you have some NaNs

Comment: @LazyCat yes that's true, I fixed it. I was answering from my phone, so it wasn't easy to double check everything ;)

Comment: @LazyCat have you had a chance to test it on real data? Any feedback on the timings?

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming. 
I checked that it runs fine, but still have to benchmark two versions. Will report the results